# Occurence of "?" leads to body being combined with the subject?

Tags: special-characters, mailto

Occurence of "?" in the body content leads to body being combined with the subject and also content after "?" is truncated

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Your Friend Wants to Share A Link&body=   <%=str%>">Email to a friend</a>
```

Comment: bad bad practice, since completely relying on a installed mailclient. Consider using your own mailer (php/cgi/whatsoever). Your problem by the way is the encoding of subject and body (use html codes for spaces etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last questionmark in an href is used to split query from path. You should url-encode your parameters. Since you seem to be using ruby, you can just use url_encode ( http://rdoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.8.7/ERB/Util:url_encode ).